# CAPM model formula for zero cost portfolio?

Tags: factor-models, capm, fama-french

Let's say I want to run a series of regressions for zero-cost portfolio Y that goes long on stocks based on high variable x and short stocks with a low variable of x. How do I run the regression, for example, for CAPM? Is it:

$$Y - r_f = a + b(market-r_f) + e$$

or

$$Y = a + b(market-r_f) + e$$

Is it the first one only if we assume that the portfolio actually has zero beta/systematic risk?

Comment: Your time series is already a tradable excess return. You do not need to subtract $r_f$ again. You can directly estmate $Y_t=\alpha+\beta (MKT_t-r_{f,t})+\varepsilon_t$.

Comment: @Kevin, why exactly is the time series an *excess* return?

Comment: @RichardHardy Because it goes long one set of assets and short another set of assets. You sell short one asset with low x and get \$1 from that and then you invest that \$1 in the asset with high x. It's a zero cost portfolio. It's an excess return.

Comment: @Kevin, I was thinking about being in excess of the risk-free rate. But now I realize the risk-free rate can be considered as 0 if you are investing 0 in the first place.

Comment: @RichardHardy Excess returns really means only that it's a zero cost portfolio. We normally do in excess of the risk-free rate if consider a standard portfolio of (long) stocks. For example the 25 portfolios on B/M and size. There I'd look at their returns in excess of $r_f$ because I need to fund my investment in any of these portfolios by borrowing from the money market. But for a high-minus-low portfolio, I don't need to include $r_f$. Check out the first table in Cochrane's (2005) first chapter. It lists prices and returns, including excess returns.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks, that makes *some* sense. You would most likely not be able to borrow risk free to invest in risky assets. Therefore, it makes more intuitive sense to me to think about either placing a given sum of money risk free or investing it in a risky asset. Then we want to earn a positive excess return from the risky investment, *excess* meaning *over the risk free rate*. But I do not mean to argue with standard definitions in finance if that is what you gave above. (I checked Cochrane's table, but the interpretation/implications are not so clear to me.)

Comment: @RichardHardy Why wouldn't be able to borrow money and invest it in risky assets? Remember we're talking asset pricing here without real-life frictions. Comparing the return on a ``given sum of money'' is difficult. Where does that money come from? Usually, you raise money (by short selling or borrowing) and then you invest that money in (perhaps risky) assets. This way, there is no inception/withdrawal of external funds and we can compare two strategies.

Comment: @Kevin, the lender has no incentive to lend risk free if there is a high probability the borrower will not be able to pay back. This is exactly what happens if the borrower puts the money in a risky asset. That is why lenders charge riskier borrowers higher rates.